# I can't add users to mysql database from php page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have done a research before posting this question here i know it has been asked for few times but non of the answers solved my issue 
i am following a tutorial and i had to create 2 php pages ,first one to connect with the sql database
Page name myfirstphpweb.php
Code:

```
$DBName ='id6_myfirstdb ';
$DBServer='localhost';
$DBUsername='id6_b';
$DBPassword='123456';
$DBConnect= new mysqli($DBServer,$DBUsername,$DBPassword,$DBName);
if($DBConnect->connect_error){
die ("connection failed:". $DBConnect->connect_error);
}
else{ echo "connection Successful! " ; 
}
```

second page to insert a user into the database 
page name: insertusersql.php
Code:

```
include 'myfirstphpweb.php';
$insertusersql="INSERT INTO users (name,password,email,address) 
          VALUES ('AVALUE','123456','AVALUE@M.com','ALOCATION');";



    if($DBConnect ->query($insertusersql)===TRUE){
             echo "User added Successfully";
             }else{
             echo "Some thing is wrong";
             }
```

I used this as well if( mysqli_query($DBConnect,$insertusersql)){

but i get the error message i put "some thing is wrong"

on mysql phpmyAdmin i get this msg "Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0066 seconds.)"

I can add users manually on phpmyAdmin

my table has 
id (int) auto increment primary key, name (varchar(70)), password(varchar(70)),email(varchar(70)),address(varchar(200)),registertime(varchar(100)) utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: What's the error message if you post that query directly into your sql client (e.g. Phpmyadmin)?

Comment: i tried this  INSERT INTO users (name,password,email,address) 
               VALUES ('AVALUE','123456','AVALUE@M.com','ALOCATION'); on my sql phpmyadmin  no error information were inserted  but when i try on my php file i still have a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $DBName ='id6_myfirstdb ';

your code is fine, but you have white space in database name. if it's not mistyping here, could be the problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
include 'myfirstphpweb.php';
$insertusersql="INSERT INTO users (name,password,email,address) 
      VALUES ('AVALUE','123456','AVALUE@M.com','ALOCATION')";

if($DBConnect->query($insertusersql)===TRUE){
         echo "User added Successfully";
         }else{
         echo "Some thing is wrong";
         }
```

Comment: Ahmed, what did you change and why?

Comment: there is a mistake you add ";" in values and you make space  before varible $DBConnect

Comment: @ahmed you just need semicolon in multiple SQL query but you can use that in single query; it's redundant but it's okay. and white space in PHP syntax will be ignore, so "$DB      ->query" and "$DB->query" are same.